# preventing IE Silverlight caching values in a grid

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer

I have a silverlight application that displays some values in a grid.  Another part of the application updates those values and saves the updates to the source data.  All of this works fine including the updating of the displayed values in the grid...until you navigate back to the page later (by say hitting refresh).  Then magically all the values in the grid are back to whatever they were the first time you went to the page.  I can check and verify that the data is in the source system correctly, I can also make it work fine by going into internet options and setting the browsing history to look for a new version of the page every time you visit the page.  But I can't guarantee that users will do this.

I have run into this MANY times before with IE but the normal fixes don't seem to work here.  I have added a timestamp to the request for the XAP file to ensure that the file is being pulled every time but somehow that is not good enough.  I've also added the pragma no-cache tag to the page and still no go.  It seems like Silverlight itself is it's own special case.  IS there something else that can be done in the SL object to make it refresh every visit??

Comment: I sympathize, for having encountered the same kind of stuff with some clients. I ended up adding magic alterations to lots of queries, but if you've already tried that, I've got nothing else to suggest.

Comment: What magic alterations might you suggest?  I have been trying to see if there is an event that is raised when the app is viewed so far loaded doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I was talking about adding some random part to all webservice queries. Which is very similar to the XAP timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

What code are you using to populate the grid?

If you load the data when the page is **created** then it will only be pulled from the database once.

If you load the data when the page is **loaded** or **navigated to** then it will be pulled from the database every time the page is displayed.

As Ken Smith says in his comment:

> move your data retrieval and population code to your main form's OnNavigate event, and out of Application_Startup

This means that if you update the data and then refresh the page it *should* show the new values.

*(I can't be 100% certain without the code)*

Comment: The viewmodel objects are created during Application_Startup for the App.xaml and the data is pulled as all the support objects are built and instantiated.

Why would changing the Internet Options of the client change the performance of the app if the event used to fill the grid was the culprit?

Comment: @Mark - I don't think the Internet Options of the client have any bearing on this. Hitting refresh simply recreates the Silverlight object thus reloading your data.

Comment: I think what Chris is saying is that you might want to move your data retrieval and population code to your main form's OnNavigate event, and out of Application_Startup.